# Dockerized PostgreSQL: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized PSQL instance and a dockerized app that connects to it. I am getting an incorrect password error trying to connect despite never setting one. Default of `postgres` doesn't work.

`compose.yml`

```
services:
  psql:
    build: database/.
    env_file: vars.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  reader:
    build: reader/.
    env_file: vars.env
    restart: always
```

`reader.py`

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    password="postgres",
    host="psql",
    port=5432)

cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "psql" (172.29.0.3), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

What could this password be? Or how is it set. I thought no default user or pass was set.

Comment: could you share: `vars.env` ?

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thought it'd be irrelevant since I was hardcoding in the `reader.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the `vars.env` file has these:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

For trouble shooting I'd remove the `vars.env` and uses a direct environment variable as the docs suggests, to see if it works:

```
  psql:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

From docs:

> The PostgreSQL image uses several environment variables which are easy
> to miss. The only variable required is POSTGRES_PASSWORD, the rest are
> optional.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Thought it'd be irrelevant since I was hardcoding in the `reader.py` file.